# Error 404 - Not Found displays when clicking pdf link in android devices

Tags: android, html, pdf, web, cross-browser

I'm currently working on a web page that opens a pdf file in a new tab using an anchor tag.

When viewed using android default browser, devices like (note 4 and tab 4) it displays **404 Not Found Error**, but this works fine when using iOS, PC and Mac

```
<a href="/sample_file.pdf" target="_blank"/>click here</a>
```

**NOTE: reference file for the pdf is relative since this will vary per environment.**

Comment: Are you sure that `href` is the same on all platforms? You can test to make sure it is the same in your browser developer tools by changing the user agent.

Comment: which browser on android?

Comment: Android default browser